# ExcelDNA passing TODAY() as parameter

Tags: excel-dna

IS it possible to write a function that accepts
=getContent("keyword",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
what should be the type of parameter then?

tried
    public static object test(object date)
    {
     return DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(date));
    } // output 41180

Comment: anybody plz help !!! I am badly stuck here:(

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Excel will evaluate the `TODAY()` function before passing your function the value. You can declare parameters as `DateTime` if you want Excel-DNA to interpreted the Excel doubles as Date/Time values. So you might write:

```
public static object getContent(string keyword, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    // do the work...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to use object datatype I tried DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(date));  but it doesn't help:( Any Idea ?

Comment: If you call DateTime.FromOAData(41108) you get a DateTime (2012/07/18 00:00:00). If you return this value to Excel and format the cell as a Date/Time, Excel will display the corresponding date.

Answer (score 0):

In the more recent versions of Excel DNA, 'DateTime' parameters are not supported. You will need to use double, and then in your C# method body convert the double to DateTime using DateTime.FromOADate().

```
public static object getContent(string keyword, double startDate, double endDate)
{
    DateTime firstDate = DateTime.FromOADate(startDate);
    DateTime lastDate = DateTime.FromOADate(endDate);

    // do the work...
    return result;
}
```